# Error al consumir servicio web POST urlencoded con Android Studio retrofit2

Tags: android, android-studio, post, retrofit, urlencoding

Recién estoy probando consumo de servicios con Android Studio y me han funcionado bien servicios GET, pero con servicios POST no me funciona. He probado varias formas que he encontrado por ahí y la respuesta siempre se va por el lado de onFailure.

En mi interface tengo lo siguiente:

```
public interface APIService {

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("nombreServicio")
@Headers("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
Call<RespuestaPost> postRegistrar(
        @Field("param1") String param1,
        @Field("param2") String param2,
        @Field("param3") String param3); }
```

La clase RespuestaPost con sus respectivos set y get:

```
public class RespuestaPost {
    private String mensaje, respuesta, data;
    private int estado;
    //AQUÍ TODOS LOS MÉTODOS SET Y GET
}
```

El cliente retrofit que ha funcionado para servicios GET:

```
public class RetrofitClient {
    public static final String BASE_URL = "https://192.168.1.xx:xxxx/serviciosExternos/api/v1/app/";
    public static APIService RETROFIT_CLIENT;

    public static APIService getInstance() {
        //if REST_CLIENT is null then set-up again.
        if (RETROFIT_CLIENT == null) {
            setupRestClient();
        }
        return RETROFIT_CLIENT;
    }

    private static void setupRestClient() {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        RETROFIT_CLIENT = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
    }
}
```

Y por ultimo en mi MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 private static final String TAG = "CONSOLA: ";
 TextInputEditText etParam1, etParam2, etParam3;
 Button btn1;
 private APIService mAPIService;
 Call<RespuestaPost> call;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAPIService = RetrofitClient.getInstance();

        etParam1 = findViewById(R.id.Param1);
        etParam2 = findViewById(R.id.Param2);
        etParam3 = findViewById(R.id.Param3);

        btn1 = findViewById(R.id.Btn1);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String p1= etParam1.getText().toString().trim();
                String p2= etParam2.getText().toString().trim();
                String p3= etParam3.getText().toString().trim();
                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(p1) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(p2) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(p3)) {
                    sendPost(p1, p2, p3);
                }else{
                    //INCOMPLETO
                }
            }
        });



    }

    private void sendPost(String p1, String p2, String p3) {
        call = mAPIService.postRegistrar(p1, p2, p3);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<RespuestaPost>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<RespuestaPost> call, Response<RespuestaPost> response) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Se envió exitoso.");
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    // tasks available
                    String respuesta = response.body().toString();
                    Log.i(TAG, "Respuesta: " + respuesta);
                } else {
                    // error response, no access to resource?
                    Log.i(TAG, "1. Error response");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<RespuestaPost> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, "2. Error no se envió.");
            }
        });
  }
}
```

Con servicios GET me da la respuesta normal, pero con los servicios POST siempre arroja la respuesta de onFailure: "2. Error no se envió.".
Agradezco si alguien me pude decir si estoy haciendo algo mal en el proceso, ya que los servicios funcionan correctamente al consumirse desde otros lados como Postman.

**Edito:** 
Tras poner en `Log.e(TAG, "2. Error no se envió. "+t.getMessage());` Me ha salido el siguiente error:

> java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for
>   certification path not found.

**Edito:**
El error era por el certificado SSL.
En mi caso la solución dada por Retrofit se encuentra en el siguiente enlace:
[Retrofit 2 - Cómo confiar en certificados SSL no seguros (autofirmados, caducados)](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-trust-unsafe-ssl-certificates-self-signed-expired)